# Proving that $\ln\frac{1-x}{\sqrt{1-2\delta(1-x)}-x}$ is convex with respect to $x$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

I am working on an optimisation problem and I am trying to prove that a binary function is convex for one of its independent variables. The function is:
$$f(x,\delta)=\ln \frac{1-x}{\sqrt{1-2\delta(1-x)}-x},$$
where $x \in [0,1]$ and $\delta \in \left[0,\dfrac{1}{2}\right]$. I want to prove that $f(x,\delta)$ is a convex function of $x$.

Actually, I have learned that it is true using Mathematica by graphing it, except at the point that $x=1$. However, I do not know how to prove it mathematically. I have already tried to prove it by calculating $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$, which is
$$-\frac{1}{(-1+x)^2}+\frac{\left(-1+\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{\smash[b]{1-2(1-x) \delta}}}\right)^2}{(-x+\sqrt{1-2(1-x) \delta})^2}+\frac{\delta^2}{(1-2(1-x) \delta)^{3 / 2}(-x+\sqrt{1-2(1-x) \delta})}.$$
However, I cannot prove that it is always larger than $0$.

I hope someone can give me some help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Remark*: We use Maple.

We have
$$\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = \frac{(2\delta + u - 1)^4}{8\delta u^3(u + x)^2(1 + x - 2\delta)^2}\cdot [4(1-\delta)u + 6\delta x - 8\delta + 4] \ge 0$$
where $u = \sqrt{1 - 2(1 - x)\delta}$.

We are done.

Comment: It is very useful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @曹宇翔 You are welcome.